# mysql 8 packages kept back on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql, dependencies

I have an ubuntu 18 box where I installed mysql server 8. After upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 it started to complain that there are two packages to be updated: mysql-server and mysql-client.

Each time I do `sudo apt upgrade` it says that `mysql-server and mysql-client` packages have been kept back.

I have tried to do `sudo apt dist-upgrade` but the packages are still kept back.

I finally tried to do `sudo mysql install mysql-server mysql-client` but I get the most verbose feedback on this issue:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
> been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
> resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mysql-client :
> Depends: mysql-client-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
> mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-8.0 but it is not going to be
> installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
> packages.

How to solve this is out of my knowledge so far.
Note: I know there are similar questions on this site. But their solutions are already described here as applied without any positive result.

Comment: Same.  Fwiw, it appears to be a dependancy issue on my end, the upgraded packages want to use:

mysql-server-8.0 (and the like)

where the current install is using:

mysql-community-server, mysql-server (and etc)

same for the client variants.